# В каком формате хранить данные?

Tags: python, анализ-данных, хранение-данных, обработка-данных

Xочу провести небольшое исследование на тему трудности/легкости произношения последовательности из трех согласных. Для этого, я сделал скрипт, который генерирует случайный набор из 5 букв, спрашивает пользователя, насколько сложно ему было произнести слово, а затем печатает небольшую таблицу с данными следующего вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В каком формате и в какой форме будет лучше всего сохранить эти данные так, чтобы потом было легко и удобно все это дело извлекать и смотреть на возможные корреляции?

Comment: Если кратко, то [pandas](https://habr.com/ru/post/196980/) - отличный вариант, датасаентисты его обожают.

Comment: 1) как вам уже сказали, используйте pandas. 2) "переднеязычный" пишется слитно 3) опрос пользователя в таком ключе - не самое объективное исследование.

Comment: @strawdog спасибо! Особо объективное мне не нужно, это homebrew, так сказать, публиковаться не буду. Пишу генератор фентезийных имен, хочется иметь какое-то подобие контроля над благозвучием.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Обрабатывать табличные данные удобнее всего в [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html).

Pandas умеет работать со многими форматами хранения данных, но выбор лучшего формата зависит от многих параметров.

Например если вы часто работаете с типами данных данных, которые Pandas не умеет парсить неявно, например с `date`, `datetime`, `interval`, `bool`, etc. то такие данные лучше хранить в бинарных форматах (смотрите ниже) или в БД, чтобы избежать повторного парсинга указанных выше типов данных.

---

Вот осоновные форматы хранения данных, которые поддерживаются в Pandas и их **плюсы** и **минусы**:

- `Python Pickle`

  - плюсы:

    - быстрое чтение & запись
    - данные хранятся с нужными типами данных - не нужно их повторно парсить
  - минусы:

    - может быть несовместимо с новыми версиями Python/Pandas
    - работать с этим форматом данных можно только в Python
- `CSV`, `TSV`, `fixed-width format`

  - плюсы:

    - совместимость - можно работать с любым ЯП / БД
    - легкость работы и обработки (можно использовать утилиты командной строки и текстовые редакторы)
  - минусы:

    - необходимость каждый раз парсить данные, чтобы распознать числа и строки. Столбцы с датами нужно явно указывать при парсинге.
    - медленное чтение и запись
    - нет поддержки быстрых кодеков сжатия (поддерживаются: ‘gzip’, ‘bz2’, ‘zip’, ‘xz’)
- `Excel`

  - плюсы:

    - удобно вручную проверять / редактировать данные в Excel
    - совместимость: многие сторонние ЯП и БД поддерживают работу с Excel файлами
    - можно красиво оформить данные - заморозить имена столбцов, добавить автофильтры и т.д.
  - минусы:

    - часто даты и время парсятся неправильно
    - максимальное число строк: 1,048,576 - для серъезных проектов этого слишком мало
    - очень медленная запись, не очень быстрое чтение
    - невозможно эффективно читать/писать данные по частям/кускам
- `HDF5`

  - плюсы:

    - хранение данных в бинарном виде. Ттип данных при этом запоминается и не нужно повторно парсить такие данные
    - очень быстрое чтение и запись
    - данные хранятся с нужными типами данных - не нужно их повторно парсить
    - поддержка быстрого кодека сжатия `BLOSC`
    - поддержка индексирования многих столбцов
    - возможность поиска по индексам - т.е. можно фильтровать данные, не читая весь датасет в память
    - совместимость:  (C, C++, Java, Python, C# and Fortran)
  - минусы:

    - мне неизвестны
- `Parquet`

  - плюсы:

    - самый быстрый из перечисленных форматов
    - основан на Apache Arrow - быстро и активно развивается
    - данные хранятся с нужными типами данных - не нужно их повторно парсить
    - поддержка одного из самых быстрых кодеков сжатия - `snappy`
    - совместимость: (C++, Java, Python, PHP)
    - поддержка партиционирования данных
  - минусы:

    - невозможность дописывать данные в существующий Parquet файл из Pandas - единственный серъезный минус данного формата. Надеюсь его скоро устранят.
    - формат достаточно молодой, поэтому иногда не хватает некоторых фич или некоторые
      фичи быстро устаревают (`deprecated`)
- `SQL DB` (используя `SQLAlchemy` в качестве прослойки)

  - плюсы:

    - все те плюсы, которые дает нам используемая СУБД
    - читать данные можно используя SQL - т.е. мы можем легко фильтровать данные, обхединять данные из многих таблиц и т.д.
    - данные хранятся с нужными типами данных - не нужно их повторно парсить
  - минусы:

    - для некоторых БД при сохранении столбцов со строками, Pandas сохранят их с типом CLOB, что обычно очень медленно работает. [Решается при помощи параметра `df.to_sql(..., dtypes={...})`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42769557/5741205)
- `Google BigQuery`

  - плюсы:

    - все плюсы, которые дает нам `Google BigQuery`
    - To Be Done...
  - минусы:

    - To Be Done...
- `Amazon S3`

  - плюсы:

    - все плюсы, которые дает нам `Amazon S3`
    - To Be Done...
  - минусы:

    - To Be Done...
- [`ORC`](https://orc.apache.org/)

  - плюсы:

    - To Be Done...
  - минусы:

    - To Be Done...
- `Stata`

  - плюсы:

    - To Be Done...
  - минусы:

    - To Be Done...